# Dots at the end of a function in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, draw

When using `tikz` to plot a function, a certain domain has to be specified. However, if the function continues outside of the specified domain, it would be nice to have the classical three dots at the margins of it, indicating that the function indeed continues.

I can't get my head around to how to accomplish that, any help is very appreciated.

A very simple MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain=-1.5:1.5, smooth, samples=250] plot (\x,{\x*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, the two ends of the parabola don't display any dot.

Comment: Just a comment! It is normal for functions to be defined outside the domain where they are plotted, but it is not normal to put dots. In my opinion this will only add confusion. To draw axis and keep plots consistent, have a look at `PGFPlots`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[continue/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0 with {\draw[continuation] (0pt,0pt) -- (-#1,0pt);},
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[continuation] (0pt,0pt) -- (#1,0pt);}
}},continue/.default=2em,continuation/.style={densely dotted}]
    \draw[continue] plot[domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=250] (\x,{\x*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this proposal it uses decorations, so does not always work with `smooth`. In particular, in your use-case it doesn't. However, 250 samples is very generous and there is no real difference between smooth and not smooth (in this case). In cases where this makes a difference you can decorate a non-smooth plot and draw a smooth one:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[continue/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0 with {\draw[continuation] (0pt,0pt) -- (-#1,0pt);},
mark=at position 1 with {\draw[continuation] (0pt,0pt) -- (#1,0pt);}
}},continue/.default=2em,continuation/.style={densely dotted}]
    \path[continue] plot[domain=-1.5:1.5, samples=250] (\x,{\x*\x});
    \draw plot[domain=-1.5:1.5,smooth, samples=250] (\x,{\x*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```